# how to transfer type of data in Tesorflow code

Tags: tensorflow

Assuming the two models has been established in tensorflow,the model1 followed by model2.

The condition is that the output's type of model1 is a "tensor" and
the input type of model2 is requiring "ndarray"  in creating structure of graph's model.(the data don't flow the graph)  If we haven't build two or more Session, how we can combine model1 with model2.

(In fact, The library fuction requiring the input's type is "ndarray" can be call in  model2. I don't want to code this process)

The sample is following

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

img = cv2.read("star_sky.jpg")#assumpting  shape of image is (256,256,3)


x_input = tf.placeholder(shape=(1,256,256,3),dtype=tf.float32)

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,3]),dtype = tf.float32)

x_output_temp = tf.nn.conv2d(x_input,W,[1,1,1,1],padding="SAME")

#the other model want to use x_output to get Canny edge of image

x_output_ = x_output_temp[0]
x_output = cv2.Canny(x_output_,100,200)#number is parameter of threshold

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    img = [img]
    x_output.eval({x_input:img})
```

Comment: Please post some sample code showing what your use-case is

Comment: I'm sorry to the wrong way to question. The sample is placed

Comment: Ok, two things.
Firstly, I guess you mean `cv2.imread` (read doesn't exist). Secondly, if you want to use the canny edge detector from `cv2`, you'll need to first run the Tensorflow network up to its output in your `sess.run`, and with that you'll call `cv2.Canny`. Opencv's canny cannot take tensors as input and won't return tensors to you, it works with numpy arrays only

Comment: I guess the path of image can exist. the Second is my problem. If i want to use this sample,  will I write similar code by myself ?(i don't want to build two graph to run)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cv2 to process a tensorflow Tensor you need to do it inside a tf.py_func (which will convert the tensor to an ndarray at graph execution time and run the python code you pass on that array)